# How to move cell contents down one cell when that cell has numbers in it?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to develop a VBA program to move cell contents and I only wish to use VBA (would like to add more to my program and so learn as much as I can using VBA). I need to move the contents down one cell but I’m not sure how does the program move contents down from one cell to the next if the next cell is full without overwriting it and then move that one down. I’ve included a jpeg of my excel sheet.
I hope you can help.

I'm trying to have the program move all the number sets down in the column E1:E12.
I need the program to move the set of numbers (could be more than one set of numbers in the range) down to the following cell below it and increase the last number in the set (no limit to the count). So in the example of cell E1 (8-16) would move to E2 and become 8-17 (cell E1 would be blank when after the move). When sets of number are located in cell E12 they would move to E1 but still increase the last number and would go round and round (E1 to E12 and back). How does the program move contents down from one cell to the next if the next cell is full without overwriting it and then move that one down, if this makes sense. An example is cell E12, how does it move up to E1 if E1 is full but has to be moved?

That’s it, thanks so much for any help.

[my Excel sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTKS0.jpg)

Comment: First, use the macro recorder - It will show you exactly what you can do. Second, do a quick review of msdn Excel VBA reference. The method you're looking for is Range.Insert  -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-insert-method-excel

Comment: Didn't you already ask this same question?  I had thought there were answers there...

Comment: Thank-you so much for your help. I will read your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rng As Range, tmp, i As Long

    Set rng = Range("E1:E12")
    tmp = rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count).Value
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 2 Step -1
        rng.Cells(i).Value = Increment(rng.Cells(i - 1).Value)
    Next i
    rng.Cells(1).Value = Increment(tmp)

End Sub

'If value has a dash, increment the second number
'  Assumes any value with a dash has a number on either side...
Function Increment(v)
    Dim rv, arr
    rv = v
    arr = Split(v, "-")
    If UBound(arr) = 1 Then rv = arr(0) & "-" & CLng(arr(1)) + 1
    Increment = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank- you for your solution Mr. Williams. I will go over this during the next few days and post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

using `Dictionary` object:

```
Sub ShiftAndIncrease()
    Dim cell As Range, key As Variant
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("E1:E12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '
            .Item(cell.Row Mod 12 + 1) = Increase(cell.Value2)
        Next
        Range("E1:E12").ClearContents
        For Each key In .keys
            Range("E" & key).Value = "'" & .Item(key)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function Increase(v As Variant)
    Increase = Split(v, "-")(0) & "-" & Split(v, "-")(1) + 1
End Function
```

Comment: Thank- you for your solution. I will go over this during the next few days.